# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) while installing google or-tools

Tags: python, or-tools

Trying to install or-tools but getting the error mentioned below. Below is the complete error code while running the or-tools installation command.

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Setting up python-colorama (0.3.2-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-colorama (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-distlib (0.1.9-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-distlib (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-html5lib (0.999-3) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-html5lib (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-setuptools (5.5.1-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-setuptools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-pip:
 python-pip depends on python-colorama; however:
  Package python-colorama is not configured yet.
 python-pip depends on python-distlib; however:
  Package python-distlib is not configured yet.
 python-pip depends on python-html5lib; however:
  Package python-html5lib is not configured yet.
 python-pip depends on python-setuptools (>= 0.6c1); however:
  Package python-setuptools is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-pip (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-wheel (0.24.0-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-wheel (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-colorama
 python-distlib
 python-html5lib
 python-setuptools
 python-pip
 python-wheel
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Command for installing or-tools.

```
    sudo apt-get -y install python3-dev python3-wheel python3-setuptools python3-six
```

what do i need to do to fix this and install or-tools?
Do i need to remove the packages causing issues. Already have a project running and am not sure if removing those would have an impact.

Comment: That's not a programming question. Check the stackexchange network for a site that fits better, please.

Comment: And please provide the detailed error.

Comment: @GenoChen, have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

The log already shows,

> ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

Then you just need to install that module, maybe using `pip` or `easy_install`.

```
$ pip install configparser
```

Comment: **Tried installing ConfigParser. Using pip it said**            Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
ImportError: No module named 'pip._internal'  **and with easy_install** Searching for configparser
Best match: configparser 3.5.0
Processing configparser-3.5.0-py3.4.egg
configparser 3.5.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/configparser-3.5.0-py3.4.egg
Processing dependencies for configparser
Finished processing dependencies for configparser

Comment: @python_user Oh, your `pip` seems corrupted, and configparser has been installed as `easy_install` said. Did you made a `virtualenv`?